# How to Store Hta/Html File in Project Resources and Use in Program

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resources, hta

I have added an `.hta` file to my applciation's resources like so:

[image]

And I would like to display this by using the line:

`Process.Start("explorer.exe", @"Path\To\File.hta");`

This works when the file is on my system, but when I try displaying the `.hta` with:

`Process.Start("explorer.exe", Properties.Resources.htatest);`

I see this error:

> There is no program associated to perform the requested action. Please install a program or, if one is already installed, create an association in the Default Programs control panel.

Is it possible to store an `.hta` in my project resources and then call it from the Program?

For reference, here is the code which exists inside the `.hta`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>IT Support - Message</title>
    </head>
    <script language = "VBScript">
        window.setInterval "setfocus()", 100
        Function setfocus
            window.focus()
        End Function
    </script>

    <body>
        <div style="margin-top:10%;">
            <h1 style="font-family:Segoe UI; color:#AF2B71; text-align: center; margin-top: 100pt">Message Heading</h1>
            <p style="font-family:Segoe UI; text-align: center"><strong/>This is a message which will be displayed to the user. </p>    
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Explorer.exe requires a file, it has no way to dig an embedded resource out of your executable.  Embedding the .hta just isn't very useful.  Instead, add it to your project with Project > Add Existing Item and set its Copy to Output Directory property to "Copy if newer".

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for your comment Hans - that is what I am currently planning on doing, but I thought it would be better to avoid having to hardcode the path or name of the file. For example if I add the `hta` as a file, then the line to call would be `Process.Start("explorer.exe", "NameOfFile.hta");`, which introduces hard-coded strings into my program. But if that is the way to do it then so be it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this will have to be added as a project resource and then copied into the output directory.

Explorer has no way of extracting files which have been embedded into an executable.